# why there is no any search result?

Tags: magento

```
 <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <label>Quick Search Form</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">

        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

i want to make the layout to `page/2columns-left.phtml`. and don't show `<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>`

so  i removed the above code.  when i tested the search function. it shows `Your search returns no results.`

when i remained the code. the search function is ok, but the layout of the left is unorder. how to correct it. thank you.

Comment: yes. i have cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your left navigation by adding one more line in your xml file:

```
<remove name="catalogsearch.leftnav" />
```

Comment: inside `<reference name="left">`. also clear cache after this change.